# How to sum cells based on background colors

Tags: excel, excel-2010

how to sum cells based on the background colors in MS Excel 2010. I have tried

```
=colorfunction(B2,F12:F192,TRUE)
```

but it is not working

Comment: You will probably need VBA for this. Formulas don't consider the formatting of cells (except a few which consider the number formatting). And `colorfunction` is not a valid function in Excel 2010.

Comment: what is `colorfunction`?

Comment: see [`this`](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/450188-color-function-excel-2007-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try out something which I wrote quickly. Yes, it can be improved to cover and handle all possible cases. But leaving that as a homework for you.

```
  Function clrsum(var As Range)
  FirstRow = var.Cells(1, 1).Row
  LastRow = var(var.Count).Row
  col = var.Cells(1, 1).Column

  For i = FirstRow To LastRow
      If Cells(i, col).Interior.ColorIndex = <put some color index here> Then
          clrsum = clrsum + Cells(i, col)
      End If
  Next
  End Function
```

Then use formula like   =clrsum(A1:A10)